# CheckBox seletion on space bar press

Tags: wpf, checkbox, wpfdatagrid

we are using wpf, want to select templated checkbox of datagrid on space bar press when an item get selected in the datagrid. Kindly help me to achieve the same.

Any suggestion will highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

set IsTabStop=True property of the checkbox and thus the checkbox will be selected and deselected on hitting spacebar.Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but we already tried above given approach, it works fine in case of tab pressing inside datagrid. but won't work when we select an item of datagrid through mouse click. Kindly suggest.